# Summing Two DataFrames by Index

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], index=[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ], columns=['A'])  
df2 = pd.DataFrame([ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], index=[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], columns=['A'])
```

I want to return the DataFrame which will be the sum of the two for each row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], columns=['A'])
```

of course, the idea is that I don't know what the actual indices are, so the intersection could be empty and I'd get a concatenation of both DataFrames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can concatenate by row, fill missing values by 0, and sum by row:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    1
dtype: float64
```

If you want it as a DataFrame, simply do

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'A': pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)})
```

(Also, note that if you need to do this just for specific *Series* `A`, Just use

```
pd.concat([df1.A, df2.A], axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

)